# Intellij IDEA copy package + class name for Spring application config

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Is there a **quick way to copy class package + name to the clip board**, e.g.

```
de.mypackage.unit.HelloWorld
```

As a Spring developer I need this on a regular basis to define beans in the `application-context.xml` and I find myself copy and pasting the stuff manually this wasting valuable seconds.

I am aware of *Ctrl + Alt + Shift + c* to copy class references, but the format is not quite right:

```
de/mypackage/unit/HelloWorld.java:73
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put your caret on the class name, the "Copy Reference" action (Ctrl-Alt-Shift-C) will put exactly what you need into the clipboard.

Note that IntelliJ IDEA supports class name completion in application-context.xml as well.

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Shift-C only puts the class name into the clipboard for me.

Comment: yeah this doesn't work for me either. It only copies class name.

Answer (score 1):

"Copy Reference" puts multiple formats to the clipboard. At least that's what I presume after a quick test. IIRC, this behaviour changed some month ago.

- Pasting into a javadoc comment section puts the fully qualified class or method name.
- Pasting somewhere else in the file, or into another application, only gives you the class or method name.